# Merge one branch into multiple other branches using single git command

Tags: git, github, merge

I have been looking for a solution through which It's possible to merge one branch into multiple other branches with single git command, but couldn't find an answer.

**Why I want to do it and What I want to do it?**

Is: I have a single **Base** branch that contains all `base code` and that will be merged into multiple other branches as:

> base branch: `main-code`

> other branches: `website-clone-1, website-clone-2, website-clone-3 ...`

So actually, I have multiple websites configured with a single repository but on different branches. So normally, If there is a change that needs to be replicated on all other websites, I will do it firstly on the `main-code` branch and then would need to check out each of the website branches and then merge theirs.

So to overcome this repetitive process I'm looking for a solution through which it would be easier for me to merge changes into all other branches with a single line of command instead of doing it on all branches one by one.

Any kind of help will be appreciated.
Cheers!

Comment: Due to how Git works, a single command is not possible because you need to checkout the target branch in case there is a conflict that needs solving by the user in the working directory. So your only solution is writing a script that checkout and merge for each branch.

Answer (score 2):

I am not aware of any way to do this with a single command but nothing stops you from creating an alias for a simple script like:

```
git for-each-ref --format="%(refname:lstrip=2)" refs/heads/website-clone-* | 
while read branch
do
    git checkout $branch
    git merge -m "your commit message" main-code
done
```

`git-foreach-ref` loops over the branches that starts with `website-clone-*` and returns their abbreviated `refname`. With `lstrip` you remove the first n slashes, so make sure you do not insert any additional subpath when naming a branch. The alternative would be to use `:short`, but it returns the shortest unambiguous refname. This means that if you have a tag and a branch with the same name, it will return the complete refname, which would take the `checkout` to a detached state, without merging the actual branch.

The worst part of this script is the fixed commit message, that you cannot extensively customize: the only variables you can use are the branch names that are going to be merged, despite not being very useful for a commit message.

Comment: that or have a list of branch names in a file, maintained manually : `cat target-branches | while read branch ...`

Comment: @LeGEC Right, but in that case you probably need to `git add` that file too. If the branches accepting the merge follow a pattern I would use my version. Otherwise, yours is certainly the most convenient way.